# JSON Array and Jquery

Tags: json, web-services, jquery

I am invoking a ASP.Net web-service (.asmx) using j-query and my response is a json array as follows

my jquery code is:

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
dataType: "json",
    url: "http://localhost:1000/WebSite2/Service.asmx/HelloWorld",
    data: '{}',
    success: function(msg) {
        alert(msg.d);
    },
    error: function() {  
        alert("Error");   
    }
});
```

my response is:

```
 [
       {
          "id":1,
          "name":"a",
          "place":"b"
       },
       {
          "id":2,
          "name":"c",
          "place":"d"
       },
       {
          "id":3,
          "name":"e",
          "place":"f"
       }
    ]
```

I want to add each objects in array to a list using j-query .I have tried a lot of ways but failed can anyone help me

Comment: Show us what you've tried, first of all.

Comment: there's no such thing as a json array. there's just json strings which can be parsed into a native data structure, which MAY be an array. you never work with json strings directly. it's just a data encapsulation/transmission format. You always work with native structures, then convert to json strings as needed.

Comment: What do you mean by a list here..??

Comment: @Sushanth-- i am using jquery mobile  . By list i mean a simple list view

Comment: @MarcB i am novice to JSON . My doubt is if their is no thing like JSONArray .  [JSON](http://www.json.org) why the are sayin about JSONArray . [JSON-JAVA](http://www.json.org/java/index.html) we can also see this here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added the objects in the array to a ul ...

```
var data =[
   {
      "id":1,
      "name":"a",
      "place":"b"
   },
   {
      "id":2,
      "name":"c",
      "place":"d"
   },
   {
      "id":3,
      "name":"e",
      "place":"f"
   }
]​;

var html = '<ul>';

$.each(data, function(i) {
    html += '<li id="' + data[i].id + '">Name = '+ data[i].name + ' Place = ' + data[i].place + '</li>'; 
});
html += '</ul>';

$('#divList').append(html);
```

Replace the `data` with `msg.d` and it should be good..

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/dD7YR/)**

Comment: i tried this before but it doesn't work for me .actually   while running the code the value of i is taken as 96 . i don't know what is the error done by me

Comment: May be you have declared a variable i in the same scope

Comment: Copy the code into your post so that it can be looked at by a fresh pair of eyes..

Answer (score 1):

You have to convert json string to json object by using [**jquery.parseJSON**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/). You can then use the attribute names of each array object.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/HeyNS/)**

```
var jsonString =  '[{"id":1,"name":"a","place":"b"},{"id":2,"name":"c","place":"d"}, {  "id":3,"name":"e","place":"f"}]';

jsonArray = $.parseJSON(jsonString );

for(i=0; i < jsonArray.length; i++)
{
    alert(jsonArray[i].id);
    alert(jsonArray[i].name);
    alert(jsonArray[i].place);
}
```

​

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work for you. No promises, but it's a start:

JS

```
success: function(msg) {
    var len = msg.d.length;
    var message = msg.d;
    for (var i=0; i < len; i++)
       {
        $('ul.container').append('<li id="' +message[i].id+  '" place="' +  message[i].place +  '">' +  message[i].name +  '</li>);
       }
},
```

HTML

```
<ul class="container">

</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dD7YR/2/)**

```
var jsondata =[
{
  "id":1,
  "name":"a",
  "place":"b"
},
{
  "id":2,
  "name":"c",
  "place":"d"
},
{
  "id":3,
  "name":"e",
  "place":"f"
}
];


$.each(jsondata, function(key,val) {
 $.each(val, function(k,v){   
      alert(v);
 });
});
```